# insert wrong order in postgresql (using pro c)

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, embedded-sql

I wanted to insert data to psql from a text file with pro*c, after inserting data with my pro*c  program ,the order of data in psql was different from the text file sometimes.

there was no any sql error in the process, I found the problem when I select * from table.

Did there have some method could confirm the order which I inserted the same as the order in database(psql) ?

thanks!

for example:

> table: testtable
>  id int 
> name char(20)
>
> txt file:
>   100  amy
>   200  john
>   300  joy
>   400  ruby

but the data in psql is like:

> 200  john
>   300  joy
>   400  ruby
>   100  amy

my program:

```c
EXEC  SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
int id;
char name[20];
int id_ind, name_ind;
EXEC  SQL ENDDECLARE SECTION;

main ()
{
   EXEC CONNECT TO　SQL ....

   while ( still have data ){
     read_data_from_file()
     put_data_in_host_varable();

     EXEC SQL INSERT INTO testtable( id, name )
     VALUES (:id INDICATOR id_ind, :name INDICATOR name_ind)
   }
   EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
   EXEC SQL DISCONNECT ALL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-order.html) *"If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on.*

So the typical solution is to add a unique, incremented integer identifier and sort by it in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 ORDER BY id;
```

Alternatively you could use a column like `INSERT_DATE` and fill it with a time stamp.

***p.s.***: check data type `SERIAL` in chapter 8.1.4 at the [Numeric Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) documentation

Answer (score 1):

Data loaded into relational database has no inherent order. If you want specific order of the selected data you should use "order by" in your select. It is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve data from relational databases without explicitly specifying the order you want the data in (using an `order by` clause) you'll get a set in random order back. If you care about the order then specify it when you retrieve the data. Don't worry about the order the database choose to store items in.

A statement like `select * from ...` has no order and you should expect none.